# UBUNTU 16.04 Server, How to Setup exim4 to reject dangerous files

Tags: 16.04, server

I have an ubuntu 16.04 server installation running exim4 splitted configuration and I want to delete or ban all incoming email having .jar .ace .exe and the rest dangerous attachments. 
I have read in the internet various receipts but I am not sure what exactly I need to do in exim4 splitted configuration files. 
Can somebody of you, give me an in details guidance?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Mike Kranidis

Answer (score 0):

Exim is a low level mail transport agent, it's not designed to look at the content of messages. If you google 'ubuntu exim4 spamassassin clamav' you can find out how to install the type of filters you need to achieve this.